# account linking for google actions

Tags: oauth

I am trying to set up account linking for actions with google. I have a simple oauth flow that works fine in the browser, but I am trying to link it to my google action project.

I have whitelisted the following redirect url in my google cloud project: 
https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/g-home-v2

In the google actions console, my authorization url is:
https://3fdbc214.ngrok.io/authorize

and my token url is:
https://3fdbc214.ngrok.io/token

After testing the authentication in the actions on google console I get this error message:
  ""Invalid response from g-home-v2_dev
    Re-run linking flow""

Below are my token and auth views:

```
@app.route('/token')
def get_token():
  token = {'token':'1234abcd'}
  return flask.jsonify(token)

@app.route('/authorize')
def authorize():
  flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
    CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
  flow.redirect_uri = 'https://oauth- \
    redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/g-home-v2'

  authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(
    access_type='offline',
    include_granted_scopes='true')

  flask.session['state'] = state

  return flask.redirect(authorization_url)
```

Any help at all is appreciated thanks!